Fantasy manga in which a noble lady is in a coma and her parents hire a magician who transfers a different soul into her body
The plot is that the female lead is in a coma, then the parents hire a magician, but the magician transfers a different soul into her body because that's the only option left.

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

i think i read this one. but cant remember what happens. can you remember if it was otome? or if the mc becomes a doctor/adventurer or goes to school, or engaged to marry the prince. anything?
